# How to draw a fading, dissolving color at Java?

Tags: java, graphics, cloud, effect, fading

I would like to create a fading color effect, something like a cloud. A transition between
two Color. I found a [link](http://forum.sa-mp.com/showthread.php?t=426610). But, at this topic, the writer define an bitmap pixel by pixel. Is there an other way to do this, like a `fadingDrawable` class? Or this is the most effective way of fading?

Comment: Have you considered using a [`LinearGradientPaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/LinearGradientPaint.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what specific libraries you're using, I can't be too specific, but as far as I know:

Most graphics libraries include some gradient functionality - this will probably be relatively fast.

And if they don't, I can't see any way to do it other than drawing the gradient pixel by pixel

Comment: I found what i wanted in gradients! Thank you!